# Use storyboard segue from custom tableview cell

Tags: swift

everyone!

In my Main controller(MainController.swift) I have table view with custom table view cell(custom class with xlb, TableViewCell.swift and TableViewCell.xlb).

In storyboard I created segue from main controller to other view controller(PromoViewController.swift).

Now my decision is:
in TableViewCell class I add tap gesture to some cells and call func that post notification. In MainViewController I added observer, and when I tap on cell code works, but I have warning in console "...whose view is not in the window hierarchy"

Comment: You might be following an over complicated route for a simple end result. What are you trying to achieve exactly? How should the application behave?

Answer (score 0):

include a closure in the cell.

Your cell.swift

```
var didTap(() -> ())?
```

While dequeueing in cell:

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! Cell


cell.didTap = {
                //perform segue here
     }
```

call closure from cell for example on button click when you want segue to happen.

```
didTap?()
```